# Multiple endpoints of SignalR in the same server

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I figured this question might have been asked before, but I have found no success implementation yet, so that prompted me to ask a new one.

My scenario is looking like this: I have one server (running under an ASP.Net  site). A main SignalR server is self-hosted within the application using OWIN. Let's say this is running under `localhost:8181`. I have one central Hub that contains all the necessary functions to communicate between the client and the server itself. Under normal usage, the client would make a call to this endpoint: `http://localhost:8181/signalr/hubs`.

Now, I would like to add another different endpoint of SignalR, like `http://localhost:8282/signalr2/hubs`. The reason is that, in the central Hub, I have a function that only used by a specific client. The special client is the only client that I want to be able to invoke that function and within it, the data is transferred to other clients in the first endpoints. In theory, I could make use one endpoint and manage them, but I would like to separate out the special client for easy debugging and maintenance, as well as maybe performance improvement.

Right now, I can start them both using different configurations in the same ASP.Net application. Connections from all clients, including the special client are working. Except, at this point, I do not know a good way to filter the special client and send the data to other clients.

Below is the configuration code for both endpoints that I have implemented:

```
public class SignalRStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJavaScriptProxies = true
        };

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseErrorPage(new Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics.ErrorPageOptions { ShowExceptionDetails = true });
        app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    }
}

public class SignalR2Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {           
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
        };

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseErrorPage(new Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics.ErrorPageOptions { ShowExceptionDetails = true });
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr2", hubConfiguration);
    }
}
```

In the `Application_Start()`, I added these:

```
_signalR = WebApp.Start<SignalRStartup>("http://localhost:8181");

_signalR2 = WebApp.Start<SignalR2Startup>("http://localhost:8282");
```

Sample Hub code:

```
[HubName("NotificationHub")]

public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    // Special client invoke this, the msg is passed to other clients in the 8181 endpoint
    public void A(string msg)
    {
        // This Clients object should refer to other clients in 8181 endpoint
        Clients.All.sendMsg(msg);
    }
}
```

Because of the `Clients` is resolved automatically by `GlobalHost`, that means its include all the client, without any exception.
So my question is that what is the correct implementation in order to achieve my scenario? Also, if we use the proper implementation, how to figure out the correct clients so send the message that can exclude the ?

To summarize:

```
SignalR 1 & SignalR 2 has same NotificationHub with function A
Client 1 -> SignalR 1 (localhost:8181)    
Client 2 -> SignalR 1 (localhost:8181)    
SpecialClient -> Signalr 2 (localhost:8282)

SpecialClient invoke A(), in which, data is send to Client 1 & Client 2, exclude SpecialClient
```

Answer (score 0):

> The special client is the only client that I want to be able to invoke
>   that function and within it, the data is transferred to other clients

The easiest way is to not separate them.

In some manner you have to know what makes that client "special" and with that you can put them in a role to give them access to methods other clients cannot access.

Restrict access to certain methods -

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] 
public class AdminAuthHub : Hub 
{ 
}
```

Find more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

How to send data to the clients -> `Clients.Others` would send to everyone else except the sender (the special client). But you could also put your special client in a "special" group and all your other clients in "non-special" group and only broadcast to the group you want using `Clients.Group`